# How are PIDs generated on Ubuntu?

Tags: fork, pid

I've just wrote a program that forks one process. The child process just displays "HI" 200 times. The father process just says he's the father. 
I've printed out both pids.
When I run my program multiple times, I see that the parent's pid stays the same, which is normal. What I don't understand is why the child's pid keeps getting incremented by 2, and exactly 2. 
My question: Is this the standard method of pid generation in Ubuntu? Incrementing by 2?

Comment: How are you running the fork'ed process? Do you use the fork()/exec() calls?

Comment: No, I just use an if statement to check the pid.

Answer (score 1):

PIDs happen to be handed out monotonically increasing in Linux 2.6, but why does it matter which you get? Don't rely on any specific behavior. If there is a skip of +2 it might simply be because another process happened to spawn a child. Or because +1 would have reached a PID that is already in use.

Comment: I've passed the pid in between as an argument to ps, which should display the name of the corresponding process, if it exists. It turns out, there is no process with such a pid. That PID is not in use.

Answer (score 0):

Found a reference [here](http://www.unix.com/solaris/142338-process-ids.html) saying that vfork() consumes a pid as a byproduct of its operation. As well, in some cases, if you're forking from a shell script, the fork might spawn a new shell before your actual script gets involved, which would also consume a pid.

I'd suggest suspending your program between a couple forks, and see if there's another process occupying those "missing" pids.